# Why do I get warning CS0108 about a property hiding a method from a base class

Tags: c#, compiler-warnings

Given the following classes the C# compiler gives me this warning:-

CS0108 "'B.Example' hides inherited member 'A.Example(string)'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended".

```
class A
{
    public string Example(string something)
    {
        return something;
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public string Example => "B";
}
```

If use the classes running this code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        B b = new B();
        Console.WriteLine(b.Example("A"));
        Console.WriteLine(b.Example);
    }
}
```

I get the following output

```
A
B
```

Which is what I would expect.

It doesn't seem to me that anything is being hidden at all. Indeed 
if class B actually contains a simple method overload like this then I get no equivalent warning.

```
class B : A
{
    public string Example(int another) => "B";
}
```

Is there something special about a property that makes that compiler warning valid or is this a case of a false positive in the compiler?

Comment: Methods can have overloads (different signature) whereas you can't overload a method by adding a property, that's why adding a property in a derived class gives you that warning. In other words, with a variable of type B, you can easily call both overloads (second example), but you can't both access the property and the method at the same time with the first example. **Try to use the B type and see for yourself**.

Comment: Thanks Lasse. I edited the original post with an example and I seem to get what you would expect don't I?

Comment: It's a warning, not error. I'd say in most cases it's not the intent of the developer to have a property and method by the same name.

Comment: @fuzzyfelts You're right, I think that have changed, from memory it didn't work "before" but it has been years since I tested things on that level, perhaps Roslyn handles it different? So you're right, my initial comment is wrong.

Comment: If you need to override a property or method of the same name in the derived class add a prefix new prefix in the derived class e.g. "public new int TheName{ get; set; }" or rename the Method or Property to something different from the one in the base class e.g public int TheNameV2 { get; set; }

Answer (score 1):

Your first example class B will have a Property "Example", thus hiding the method Example(string) and the compiler ask you to specify the new keyword to clarify your intentions:

```
class B
{
    public string Example;
}
```

In your second example both method implementations of Example(string/int) will be visible. So no hiding by the class B implementation:

```
class B
{
    public string Example(string something);
    public string Example(int another);
}
```

Comment: For the error "Warning CS0108: 'DerivedClassName.Method()' hides inherited member 'BaseClassName.Method()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended."
e.g. "new" prefix to override the inherited member of the same name: public new string Method() { return "result V2"; }